# how to roll back web service in spring MVC

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I have a multiple webservices to be call.

Suppose I call a webservice to save some data to their local DataBase. After I get response from the webservice I check the response for following situation:

1- Let's take first service was successful and second too.
2- Let's consider the third webService fails, In this situation I need to roll back first and second web service calls!

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ravi,

There is something called as Transaction, and when it goes for Distributed, it is called as XATransaction.

Hope this helps: [basic spring based transaction](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077714/java-web-development/xa-transactions-using-spring.html)

[With and without XATransaction](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html)

You have to remember, that your requirement is **Global Transaction**, any where exception will Rollback all the Transaction(Insert...etc processing).

Answer (score 1):

There is no roll-back. Imagine the following procedure:

- You book a ticket for an event
- You book a flight to get to the event
- You want to book a hotel room near the event location.

Now there are no free rooms so you decide not to join the event. You cannot "roll back" the flight reservation. You need to cancel the flight and probably even pay a fee.

So if you have called a web service to book a flight you have to call a web service to cancel the flight.